# i seem to have the validation for anchor tag correct, however page will still send to href once button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I finally got my validation for my anchor tag.
However when I add an href and click on the button, it will still go to the website when I test it.

Is this normal?
Is there a better way to validate my anchor tag?

```
<form id="myform" method="post" name="contact_form" action="">
  <input id="cname" type="text" name="name" minlength="2" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required>
  <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" required>
  <textarea id="ccomment" rows="5" name="message" placeholder="Message..." class="form-control" required></textarea>

  <div id="send-btn">
    <a href="#" onClick="$(this).closest('form').submit();" class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" role="button">SEND</a>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="submit"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myform").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      SubmittingForm();
    },
    rules: {
      name: "required",
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      field: {
        required: true,
        digits:true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: browser cache? perhaps?

Comment: Could you publish a https://jsfiddle.net/?